# What is the correct way to indent multiline example codes in DocBlock in TypeScript file?

Tags: typescript, indentation, typescript3.0, docblocks

I have this code:

````js
  /**
   * Title of function
   *
   * @param data JSON data
   * @param rules Your rules
   * @example
   * ```
   * rules = {
   *   id: ['integer', 'required'],
   *   date_of_birth: ['iso_date', 'required'],
   *   passport: ['string', 'nullable'],
   *   identity_card_number: ['id_card_number', 'required']
   * }
   * ```
   */
  validateObject(data: any, rules: any) {
  }
````

In this case I write a fair indentation in my DocBlock's example section, but still the VSCode ignore the code indentations.

How can I force the code indentations in the example codes when VSCode show this documentation in a help bubble?

Comment: Where do you see VS Code ignoring the indentation? Hover? On suggestions?

Comment: @Matt Bierner : on hover

Comment: Works for me. If this doesn't work for you, it's a bug. Please [open an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose)